# POSTGRESQL JDBC Error Unable to recreate exception from backed error: java.io.IOException: JDBC Error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, hive, apache-pig

I am trying to run a pig script

```
register 'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/pig/jars/postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar';
register 'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/pig/jars/piggybank.jar';
a = load 'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/outage' USING PigStorage(',') AS (no:int, name:chararray, age:int);
STORE a INTO 'test' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage('org.postgresql.Driver','jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/hivedata','postgres','123','INSERT INTO test (no, name, age)values(?,?,?)');
```

I am getting the data from hive but cannot write to postgresql

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.Launcher - Backend     error message
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: JDBC error
```

Comment: please define question with proper detail....

Comment: "Can not write to PostgreSQL". Because ...? PostgreSQL version? **Exact text of any error messages**? We don't have access to your system. If you don't explain it, we can't see it. There just isn't enough info here.

Comment: sorry tht was a mistake.i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

`database "hivedata" does not exist` - here's your error.

Remember that as a rule of thumb, in Java stack straces the last `Caused By:` clause is the most relevant exception.